# Deleting a uint8_t array defined with first pointer and number of elements

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pointers

I'm calling a c++ dll from my C# program. It appears that, once a variable is passed to unmanaged code, C# doesn't want anything to do with it, as a result my program is leaking memory like crazy.

Here's the C# part of the code:

```
    byte[] bytes = MyData;
    int array_lenght = bytes.Length;
    DataProcessor(bytes, array_lenght);
```

DataProcessor is defined as

```
[DllImport("Processor", EntryPoint = "DataProcessor")]
public static extern void DataProcessor(byte[] array, int ArrayElementCount);
```

Here's the DLL side of the DataProcessor function:

```
void DataProcessor (uint8_t* InputArray, int ArrayElementCount)
// do some stuff here
```

Now it appears I need to delete this array(InputArray) from DLL, however I couldn't find a way to do that. I tried stuff like

```
delete *(InputArray + i) // inside a for loop
```

And mapping array to a vector like this and clearing it

```
std::vector<uint8_t> fckn_vector(InputArray, InputArray + ArrayElementCount);
fckn_vector.clear();
```

I'm 100% sure that there must be a very simple way to do this, however I'm not good with C++.

Comment: I'm no interop expert, but at the very least I would imagine deleting a managed object on the unmanaged side would be a *bad* idea.

Comment: Also, you might want to pin your array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx

Comment: Show us the definition of your `DataProcesor` method on the C# side.

Comment: @Luaan added the definition

Comment: Okay, in that case, you definitely shouldn't delete the array - it's handled by the marshaller. Why do you think there's a memory leak? What else are you doing in the C++ code? Are you running multiple `DataProcessor`s concurrently? Since the array is blittable, it should be pinned rather than copied over - are you perhaps having heap fragmentation issues? Try using CLRProfiler to monitor the memory layout.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freecotaskmem(v=vs.100).aspx) method:

```
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(InputArray);
```